# How to hide a specific indicator in other timeframes?

Tags: time, pine-script

```
s2    = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tfD2, outD2, gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)
plot(s2, title="Daily 20 EMA", color=color.purple,linewidth=2)
```

I want to display this only on "Daily" TF, in weekly, monthly or lower than Daily TF, I want to hide this or not plot it at all. Can I do it via script?

I have tried using `timeframe.isdaily` on plot stmt but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
drawEMA2 = timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.isweekly and timeframe.ismonthly
s2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tfD3, outD3, gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)
plot(series=drawEMA2 ? s2 :na, title="Daily 50 EMA",color=color.fuchsia,linewidth=2)
```

This works, just figured out after posting!

Comment: BTW - you can shorten it by using `not`. For example: `drawEMA2 = not timeframe.isdaily`